# CORS + Android Webview, doesn't work on device (but does on emulator)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-emulator, cors

I have a working HelloWorld phonegap program with jquery mobile sprinkled in as described here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/about/getting-started.html.  I added a little javascript to this to experiment with Cross Origin Resource Sharing:

```
<script>
$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.mobile.changePage("http://jquery.com");
});
</script>
```

This works great on the emulator (2.3), jquery.com is loaded over the jquery mobile demo.  However, on actual 2.3 Android devices (T-mobile G2 running Cyanogen, Galaxy SII, Galaxy Player) the changePage() call does nothing.

Comment: What are your cache and async fields set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mobileinit` instead of `pageinit`. Because event you bound to is normal jQuery and for jQuery mobile the initialization event is mobileinit.

`The $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages option must be set before any cross-domain request is made so we recommend wrapping this in a mobileinit handler`.

Answer (score 4):

Calling the `$.mobile.changePage()` function within the `pageinit` function sounds like a bad idea because that should cause an infinite loop. The `$.mobile.changePage()` function initializes the page specified as the `target` parameter so each time you call `$.mobile.changePage()` you also fire a `pageinit` event.

You probably want to bind to the `mobileinit` event to overwrite the `$.support.cors` variable before jQuery Mobile is initialized:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.mobile.changePage("http://jquery.com");
});
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Related documentation:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html